# Busy waiting in AWT

Tags: java, graphics, focus, awt, keylistener

Here is my problem. When I try to handle KB events, my programm do nothing. Some people belive it happening becouse of busy waiting (new thread fighting with main thread). How can I fix it?

```
public class GameCanvas extends Canvas {
    int myX = 250;
    int myY = 0;
    int speedValue = 15;
    int bottom = 480;

    GameCanvas() {
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
                switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        if (myX > 5) myX -= 5;
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                        if (myX < 480) myX += 5;
                        break;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    setGameSpeed(speedValue);
                    if (myY < bottom) {
                        myY += 5;
                    } else {
                        bottom -= 20;
                        myY = 0;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void setGameSpeed(int value) {
        try {
            sleep(value);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
        g.fillRect(myX, myY - 5, 25, 25);
        buildGameBottom(g);
    }

    void buildGameBottom(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, bottom + 20, 500, bottom + 20);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        GameCanvas gameCanvas = new GameCanvas();
        gameCanvas.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        gameCanvas.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        gameCanvas.requestFocus();
        frame.add(gameCanvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not busy waiting (you're not doing any busy waiting here).

The only problem is that the `KeyListener` is connected to the `Canvas` but the `Frame` has input focus. Try clicking on the `Canvas` and it will work.

Also, if you're using a repaint loop, you don't need to call repaint in the `KeyListener`.

And, please use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for calling Swing/AWT functions from different threads.

Moving the `requestFocus` call to after setting the frame visible should fix your problem (because you can't give something the focus that's not yet visible).